# Sets of Functions

Tags: soft-question

Please provide feedback to my answer to this question.
Question:
For all sets A,B,C if A contain in B, B contain in C and C contain in A , then A=B=C.
Answer:
True, since;
If we let x be element of A, since A contain in B, it implies that x is also an element of B, then A=B.
If we let x be element of B, since B contain in C, it implies that x is also an element of C, then B=C.
If we let x be element of C, since C contain in A, it implies that x is also an element of A, then C=A.
Thus A=B=C.

Answer (score 2):

Your answer is correct but the logic can be made more clear.
Given that $A\subset B\subset C\subset A$
So $x\in A\Rightarrow x\in B$ as $A\subset B$
 Similarly $x\in B\Rightarrow x\in A$ as $B\subset A$Thus $A=B$

Same argument will also work to prove $A=C$ since $A\subset C\subset A$

Thus $A=B=C$